# Installing Gearman on Ubuntu 10.04. Missing boost library

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman on Ubuntu and having some difficulty getting past the `make` command. I'm trying to install the `1.1.2` version.

This is the output from the make command

```
CXX    bin/error.o
CXXLD  bin/gearadmin
bin/bin_gearadmin-gearadmin.o: In function `main':
/home/john/gearmand/gearmand-1.1.2/bin/gearadmin.cc:129: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  CXX    libtest/libtest_unittest-unittest.o
make[1]: *** [bin/gearadmin] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/gearmand/gearmand-1.1.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've followed the steps on this blog post to install it - http://rdstash.blogspot.com/2012/02/installing-gearman-101-on-ubuntu-1104.html

I've run the following command to install boost, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-program-options1.40-dev libboost-thread1.40-dev -y
```

Any suggestions on how I can get it working on my system?  Let me know if I need to post any further information.

**UPDATE**

I ran a `apt-get remove` and tried to install an older version using the steps listed here - http://moffe42.blogspot.com/2011/12/installing-gearman-on-ubuntu-1004.html

Running the following command gave me this

```
sudo apt-get install gearman gearman-job-server gearman-tools libgearman4 libgearman-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgearman4: Conflicts: libgearman-server0
  libgearman6: Conflicts: libgearman-server0
E: Broken packages
```

I tried installing libgearman-server0 but then I got the following message

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  gearman-tools: Depends: libgearman6 (= 0.32-0~598-1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
  libgearman-dev: Depends: libgearman6 (= 0.32-0~598-1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

When I install this package, it just gives me the previous message (it just keeps alternating)

Comment: It may be that the version (1.1.2) of _gearman_ you are trying to compile requires a newer version of _boost_ than the one available on Ubuntu 10.04 (the instructions you mention are for 1.0.2, the requirements may have changed since then). There are _gearman_ packages available for Ubuntu 10.04 for an older version of _gearman_ (0.10), do you really need the latest _gearman_ version?

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. No, I don't need the latest version. Should I be trying something from the 0.2 branch?

Comment: I would suggest installing the Ubuntu 10.04 _gearman_ related packages as the first step. That should be the easiest solution. If that doesn't meet your requirements, then try to compile version 1.0.2 or the latest from the 1.0.x branch.

Comment: This is what I use to install when compiling it "apt-get install gearman build-essential libboost-dev libevent-dev uuid-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev"

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really find an answer to this. When I came back to this issue, I decided to update my OS to 12.04 and then run the installation. Worked flawlessly this time around.

These are the steps I used to install gearmand on 12.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc autoconf bison flex libtool make libboost-all-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev curl libevent-dev memcached uuid-dev libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install gperf
sudo apt-get install libcloog-ppl0
cd /tmp/
wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.9/+download/gearmand-1.1.9.tar.gz
tar xvzf gearmand-1.1.9.tar.gz
cd gearmand-1.1.9/
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install

sudo ldconfig
sudo pecl install gearman  #you will need to install pecl if you don't have it

#Edit INI files and add extension=gearman.so to it 
#/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
#/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini 

sudo ldconfig
```